# Can you give an O365 user "Send As Permissions" through Azure AD Graph API?

Tags: office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm creating new users through the graph API, and I'd like to give some users permission to send emails as other addresses.

Is this possible through the Azure AD Graph API?   Or is there a .NET library that would allow me to grant these permissions after the user has been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure AD Graph API used to read and modify objects such as users, groups, and contacts in a tenant. The “Send As” is the “Impersonation” feature of Exchange. It is not able to grant the permission through Azure AD Graph API.

To config the impersonation we can use the PowerShell. Here is the piece of code to config the impersonation(user1=>user2):

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential #require administrator of Exchange

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $Session

New-ManagementScope -Name "customScopeName“ -RecipientRestrictionFilter {Name -eq user2'}

New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Name "customManagementRoleAssignmentName" -Role:ApplicationImpersonation -user:User1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com -CustomRecipientWriteScope:customScopeName
```

And if you want to run the PowerShell script in C#, you can refer to [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/).